# Complexity of this function?

Tags: complexity-theory

```
void compute(int n) {
        int h = n;
        while (h > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                // do some operation
            }
            h = h / 2;
        }
 }
```

Can anybody please tell me what is the complexity( Big O ) of this function of n ??

This is actually an argument between me and a friend of mine.
my stand: complexity is O(n*log(n))
friend's stand: log(n)

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I'm a bit shocked that there are so many different answers. :-O

Comment: It converges, slowly towards a single one :-). Also it's still early in the morning, brains can't work properly yet :/

Comment: It's not a question of time, it's a question of the availability of cafeïne :)

Comment: Why *should* there be only one answer? Ο only tells you *a*  bound, not *the* bound and certainly not a *tight* bound. Now, if the OP had asked for Θ, that would be a different story, but since he *explicitly* asked for Ο, anything which is bigger than n∙log n is correct, therefore there are an infinite number of correct answers.

Comment: Sure, that's probably right. But i'm sure he wanted a precise answer, and maybe he just didn't find the Θ-key on his keyboard. :P

Comment: That's easy: &Theta; Doesn't work in the comments, unfortunately (I copy&pasted the Theta from the Wikipedia article about Landau notation), but it works just fine in questions and answers. My point is simply that there is a definite difference between Big-O, Small-O, Big-Omega, Small-Omega and Theta, and if the OP specifically asks for one of these, it doesn't make sense to answer for another one. And the OP specifically asked for Big-O, but most answers seem to answer for Theta.

Comment: I guess a lot of people don't make a big difference between them then. :-/

Answer (score 18):

I'd say since in every run, h is halved and n operations are done, it's O(n * log n).

Answer (score 9):

If this is homework (and it sounds a bit like it), then you should first try yourself.

Basically to get the complecity you look at the structure of the function, that is loops, nesting loops, etc. and determine how long they run, which inputs they depend on, etc.

In this case you have only one input, *n*. The local variable *h* starts with the same value as *n*, so it's essentially the same, complexity-wise, however, you need to keep track of how it's used.

You have essentially two nested loops here, one that runs to *n*, another one around it, that causes *h* to halve each time it's run. So this function is in O(*n* · log<sub>2</sub>*n*).

Comment: The second loop doesn't run to n/2.  Try n = a million.  The second loop is not going to run half a million times.  In fact I think this is O < O(n.sqrt(n))

Comment: Agreed, it's not n/2 which is why I deleted (and then edited) it, but no, it's not the root, see Botz3000's answer. Try n = 1024, you'll see that you get 10 iterations for the outer loop which is log_2 1024, not √1024 (which would be 32).

Comment: It helps to notice that h decreases at the same rate as the remaining nodes in a binary tree search, which is commonly known to run at O(log n)

Comment: Yes, when putting a little thought into it, it certainly becomes clear. I wonder, though, whether I should integrate the starting blurp into your answer, as you were the first with the correct one.

Comment: I should have changed my answer sooner, I got voted down whilst you got voted up!

Comment: I'm wondering, too, since my answer isn't as elaborate as yours. But it got me a badge :)

Answer (score 4):

Some operation:

```
O(x)
```

The for loop: because n >= h and 
supposing h will not be modified during "some operation":

```
O(n*x)
```

The outer while loop:

```
O(log(n)*n*x)
```

Comment: In Big-O-Notation, you can discard the constant x.

Comment: true, but i think he wouldn't have left the "x" operation commented out if it wasn't constant.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be O(n.sqrt(n))

The outer loop is obviously n, and the inner loop is sqrt(n).

EDIT: The inner loop is correctly log(n), because the number of iterations is x where 2^x = n.

Comment: I should clarify: because the inner loop is 'halving' each time, it is order n^(1/2), which is the same as sqrt(n).

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake, I was wrong on the n/2 part. But you're unfortunately equally wrong on the root. See Botz3000's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly **n*log(h)**.